# Making a rigorous argument on the series of mobius function?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, asymptotics, functional-equations, mobius-function

I was recently fiddling with the moebius function and realized I could do some manipulations on it.

### To Prove

$$ f(x) + f(x^2) + \dots = x $$

$$\implies \left(1 - \frac{13}{12 n^2}\right) \int_{0^+}^\infty  (-x)e^{-x\left(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2}\right)} f'(e^{-x\left(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2}\right)}) dx  =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag{1}$$

### Background and Manipulations

Consider the series:

$$ f(x) := \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r) x^r  \tag{2}$$

This satisfies:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty f(x^r) = f(x) + f(x^2) + \dots  = x \tag{3}$$

We will use  $x  = 1 - \epsilon =  1- \frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is a large integer.

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty f((1- \frac{1}{n})^r) =  1- \frac{1}{n} \tag{4}$$

We choose $n$ such that $(1- \frac{1}{n})^r = e^{r \ln(1- \frac{1}{n}) } \sim e^{\frac{-r}{n}  - \frac{r}{2 n^2} - \frac{r}{3 n^3}} \tag{5}$

Thus:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{nk} f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} - \frac{r}{2 n^2} - \frac{r}{3 n^3}  - \frac{r}{4 n^4}} ) =  1- \frac{1}{n}  \tag{6}$$

We now change $n \to n+1$

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{(n+1)k} f(e^{\frac{-r}{n+1} - \frac{r}{2 (n+1)^2} - \frac{r}{3(n+1)^3 } - \frac{r}{4 (n+1)^4}  } ) =  1- \frac{1}{n+1}  \tag{7}$$

Re expressing in terms of $\frac{r}{n}$

$$ \implies \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{(n+1)k} f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} \cdot (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{-1} - \frac{r}{2n^2}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-2} - \frac{r}{3n^3} \ (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{-3} - \frac{r}{4 n^4} } ) =  1- \frac{1}{n+1} \tag{8} $$

$$ \implies \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{(n+1)k} f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} \cdot (1 - \frac{1}{n} +  \frac{1}{n^2} -  \frac{1}{n^3} ) - \frac{r}{2n^2}(1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}) - \frac{r}{3n^3} \ (1 - \frac{3}{n}) - \frac{r}{4 n^4} } ) =  1- \frac{1}{n+1} \tag{9}$$

$$ \implies \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{(n+1)k} f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} + \frac{r}{2n^2} - \frac{r}{3n^3}  - \frac{5r}{6 n^4} } ) =  1- \frac{1}{n+1} \tag{10}$$

Subtracting the $n$ and simplified $n+1$ equation:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{nk} (f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} - \frac{r}{2 n^2} - \frac{r}{3 n^3} - \frac{r}{4 n^4}  } ) - f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} + \frac{r}{2n^2} - \frac{r}{3n^3}  - \frac{5r}{6 n^4} } )) + \sum_{r=kn+1}^{k(n+1)}f(e^{\frac{-r}{n+1} - \frac{r}{2 (n+1)^2} - \frac{r}{3(n+1)^3 } - \frac{r}{4 (n+1)^4}  } ))  =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag{11}$$

Taking common factor of $\exp({\frac{-r}{n}  - \frac{r}{3 n^3}})$ and resuming the second series:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{nk} (f(e^{\frac{-r}{n}  - \frac{r}{3 n^3}}e^{  - \frac{r}{2 n^2} - \frac{r}{4 n^4}  } ) - f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} - \frac{r}{3n^3}} e^{  \frac{r}{2n^2}  - \frac{5r}{6 n^4} } )) + \sum_{r=1}^{k} f(e^{\frac{-(kn+r)}{n+1} - \frac{(kn+r)}{2 (n+1)^2} - \frac{(kn+r)}{3(n+1)^3 } - \frac{(kn+r)}{4 (n+1)^4}  } )  =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)}  \tag{12}$$

Expanding the first series inside the bracket and taking $kn + r$ in the second series common:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{nk} (f(e^{\frac{-r}{n}  - \frac{r}{3 n^3}}{(1  - \frac{r}{2 n^2} - \frac{r}{4 n^4} + \frac{r^2}{8 n^4}   } )) - f(e^{\frac{-r}{n} - \frac{r}{3n^3}} {(1+  \frac{r}{2n^2}  - \frac{5r}{6 n^4} + \frac{r^2}{8 n^4} } ))  + \sum_{r=1}^{k} f(e^{\frac{-(kn+r)}{n+1} (1 - \frac{1}{2 (n+1)} - \frac{1}{3(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{4 (n+1)^3}  )} ) =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)}   \tag{13}$$

Taylor expanding and simplifying while multiplying the second series with $n+1$ in the numerator and denominator:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{nk} (f'(e^{\frac{-r}{n} - \frac{r}{3 n^3}}) {e^{\frac{-r}{n} - \frac{r}{3 n^3}}( - \frac{r}{ n^2} - \frac{13r}{12 n^4}  } )) +
(n+1) \sum_{r=1}^{k} f(e^{\frac{-kn}{n+1} (1 - \frac{1}{2 (n+1)} - \frac{1}{3(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{4 (n+1)^3})} \cdot e^{\frac{-r}{n+1} (1 - \frac{1}{2 (n+1)} - \frac{1}{3(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{4 (n+1)^3})} \frac{1}{n+1}   = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}
\tag{14}$$

Writing as an integral:

$$\implies \int_{0^+}^\infty  (-x)e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})} f'(e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})}) dx - \frac{13}{12 n^2} \int_{0^+}^\infty (-x)e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})} f'(e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})} dx) + (n+1) \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0^+}^k f(e^{- k \lambda -x \lambda} ) dx =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag{15}$$

Where $\lambda$ is a function of $n$. Taking the integral common:

$$\implies (1 - \frac{13}{12 n^2}) \int_{0^+}^\infty  (-x)e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})} f'(e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})}) dx  + (n+1) \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0^+}^k f(e^{- k \lambda -x \lambda} ) dx =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag{16}$$

Using a change of limits in the second integral $x + k \to z$:

$$\implies (1 - \frac{13}{12 n^2}) \int_{0^+}^\infty  (-x)e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})} f'(e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})}) dx  + (n+1) \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{k}^{2k} f(e^{x \lambda} ) dx =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag{17}$$

Which makes the second integral go to $0$:

$$\implies (1 - \frac{13}{12 n^2}) \int_{0^+}^\infty  (-x)e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})} f'(e^{-x(1 + \frac{1}{3 n^2})}) dx  =  \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\tag{18} $$

Can we say something $f(x)$ using the above equation?

### Question

Is it possible to make the above proof rigorous? (I've tried to provide some sort of error estimate) Can the error be improved upon? Is there a useful error bound approximation for the converting an summation into an integral? Can anyone computationally show which step of mine is wrong? (It does not seem intuitive to me)

**P.S: This post has been heavily (twice) edited to include an error. Hopefully it is now immune to some of the comments made(?)**

Comment: You use $=$ in places where there is no exact equality, so I would not say your proof is correct. Your argument isn't complete until you rigorously bound your errors.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Actually that's one of the questions I ask "What would be the error involved?" ... I'm not sure how to do it myself any pointers will be welcome :)

Comment: Most of what you wrote does not make sense. I recommend you study asymptotic big-O notations.

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) x^n, \qquad x f'(x) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(n) x^n$$ For $\Re(s) > 2$, since $\int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-nt}dt = n^{-s} \Gamma(s)$ $$\int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-t} f'(e^{-t})dt = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(n)  \int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-nt}dt = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(n)  n^{-s} \Gamma(s) = \frac{\Gamma(s) }{\zeta(s-1)}$$ (mod ed)

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^N n\mu(n)  \int_0^M t^{s-1} e^{-nt}dt =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(n)  (n^{-s} \Gamma(s)+ \mathcal{O}(N^{s} e^{-N M}))$ $=\frac{\Gamma(s) }{\zeta(s-1)}+ \mathcal{O}(\frac{N^{2-s}}{\Re(2-s)}) + \mathcal{O}(\frac{e^{-N M}}{(1-e^{-NM})^2})$

Comment: @reuns I've edited the post to use asymptotics without big O notation hopefully this will present my ideas better? Also from which line does the non-sense begin?

Comment: $\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} f((1- \frac{1}{n})^r) + \sum_{r=n}^{n^2} f((1- \frac{1}{n})^r) \sim  1- \frac{1}{n}$ doesn't make sense. $\sum_{r= 1}^N f(x^r) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k \sum_{d | k, d \le N} \mu(d) = x+\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty x^k \sum_{d | k, d \le N} \mu(d)$ $=x+\mathcal{O}(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty x^k k^\epsilon)$ where I used $\sum_{d | k} \mu(d) = 1_{k=1}$ and $\sum_{d | k} 1 = \mathcal{O}(k^\epsilon)$.

Comment: @reuns Ummm ... But we know $f(0) = 0$ ... Why can't I ignore the terms (in the $\lim n \to \infty \sum_{r=n^2 +1}^{n^3} f(\exp(-r/n- r/(2n^2)))$ ) as they tend to $0$?... I would be surprised if this estimate failed at say $n = 100$

Comment: $\sum_{r= 1}^\infty \mu(r) x^r$ converges and is analytic for $|x| < 1$. Yes $f(0) = 0$ but $f$ is unbounded and not continuous as $x \to 1^-$. And $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1- \frac{1}{n})^n = 1/e$ but here you are looking at $\lim_{n \to \infty}1- \frac{1}{n}=1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70098/discussion-between-anant-saxena-and-reuns).

Comment: @AntonioVargas I've added some sort of error estimate but I am not sure if it is correct. Your input would be useful

Comment: Your $f(x) + f(x^2) + \dots  = x$ is correct as an equation regarding $f(x)$ as a formal power series  which has different convergence properties than $f(x)$ regarded as a real valued function.

Comment: @Somos  I don't understand which step of mine is invalidated by that argument. $f(x)$ converges for $|x|$<1 nowhere in my argument do I go outside the radius of convergence.

Comment: @AnantSaxena Okay, I had to assure myself by direct computations that $f(x) + f(x^2) + \dots  = x$ was true for $|x|<1$. However limits in general and convergence of series can be tricky. Have you done any computations to test your limit claims?

Comment: @Somos I know for a fact I don't have the "correct error terms" when I convert a summation into an integral (without that it would be meaningless to compute anything). From the step where "writing as an integral." I don't know how or where I can get the error in converting a sum from an integral ...I think of this calculation mare as a blueprint rather than a finished work.

Comment: @Somos There are no serious claims in Anant's question. $\int_0^\infty t e^{-t} f'(e^{-t})dt = \frac{\Gamma(2)}{\zeta(2-1)} = 0$ where the convergence is guaranteed by the prime number theorem. @ Anant : $\sim $ means equivalent. Thus $1-\frac{1}{n} \sim 1$. What you meant are things like $1-\frac{1}{n} = \exp(-1/n)+ \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$.

Comment: @AnantSaxena You mention "this calculation" but I don't think that you meant **numerical** calculation. You have mathematical expressions but have you done any **numerical** calculations to test your claims?

Comment: @Somos no I haven't but that's because my programming skills are abysmal

Comment: @AnantSaxena That is unfortunate. A little bit of numerical calculation goes a long way. I highly recommend [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) which I think is easy to use. You don't even have to install it. You can run it in a browser and there are several other online options.

Comment: @AnantSaxena: Equation (6) is clearly wrong. At most, the infinite summation is an appoximation to the right side.

Comment: It is not very clear to me. Are you considering only the functions $f(x) := \sum_{r=1}^\infty \mu(r) x^r  \tag{2}$If so this should be above in the "to prove" section.